# Cannot hide Google Drive icon from nautilus menu

Tags: nautilus, deja-dup, google-drive, umount

Ever since I had selected my google drive account as my default storage location in `Déjà Dup`, an annoying icon with the name of my account shows up at the right side of my nautilus menu.

When I mount the drive, a desktop icon is created confirming it has been mounted. But when I try to view the drive's properties, I get this message:

[image]

Even changing the backup location to a local folder or turning off backup in `Déjà Dup` does not make the icon go away.

If i try to open the drive I get this message:

[image: error message]

As visible here, the option to remove the drive is grayed out even when it is unmounted in the right click menu:

[image: drive icon]

How do I make this go away once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Google account was added through GNOME Control Center → Online Accounts.

You can open them from terminal with

```
gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

and then remove your account from here.